# How to extract text from columns and feed them to a code on Linux (bash)?

Tags: linux, bash

Suposing I have the following textfile with spaces, tabs, whatever between those words:

```
1     test.1
2  word.2
3   whatever.5
```

I want to extract the second column (does not work with `cut -d' ' -f2 test.txt` which I cannot understand), then the piece before the decimal point, and feed that result seperately to some code. So the above text file should create three commands:

```
mycommand test
mycommand word
mycommand whatever
```

I tried the following construction:

```
cat test.txt | gawk '{print $2;}' | gawk -F[.] '{print $1;}' | xargs  -0 mycomand
```

which does not produce the desired result (i.e. creating three distinct jobs).

Questios: 
1. How to do it right?
2. How to simplify the expression
3. What is wrong with the `cut` expression?

Comment: that line with `cat` did it right on my machine

Comment: Then maybe I can put the two gawks into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `-0` argument to [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs). You are feeding newline-separated input to [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs), not NUL-separated. Additionally pass  `-n 1` to [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs) to execute `mycommand` once per input line.
Also, you may combine your [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) invocations to

```
gawk -F'[[:space:]]+|[.]' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Then only the first term (test) is passed to `mycommand`. All of the other arguments are ignored.

Comment: Perfect. What is the vertical bar in front of the rectangular brackets?

Comment: @Alex, `|` is for alternation. So the field separator is being set to one of "one or more spaces" or `.`

Answer (score 1):

```
$> grep -P -o "(?<= )[^\ \.]+" test.txt | xargs mycommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl answer in case you want another way to do it:

```
perl -ne'print (((/^\d+\s+([^\.]+)/)[0])."\n")'
```